# Get request fails in javascript

Tags: javascript, get, variable-assignment

I'm trying to call another page with javascript, but I can't imagine what is wrong.
This is what I wrote:

```
function updatesomething(id) {
   var xmlHttp = null;
   var theUrl = "";
   xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   alert('works');
   theUrl = 'testpage.php?id=' + id + '&hoeveelheid=' + document.getElementById("hoeveelheid_textfield").value;
   alert(theUrl);
   xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, false);
   xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

The first alert that shows 'works', is actually working. The second alert never shows up. But I don't know what would be wrong with assignment of 'theUrl'.

Thanks

Comment: PRO-TIP: Don't use async=false. Synchronous requests to the server block the UI and freeze it.

Comment: 99% chance that the error log in your developer console is now saying *"cannot access property 'value' on a NULL reference"*. But even if I'm wrong on that, it **will** be giving more useful information about why execution is stopping, so go look it up.

Comment: Is the Error-Console of Firefox or Chrome showing some error?

Comment: Does an input with the id `hoeveelheid_textfield` exist on the page?

Comment: This is my first piece of javascript, and never heard of the 'error console' however, I found it on Firefox, and it says: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

And indeed, I was mixing up the input id and the input name.. Very lame of me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `theUrl = 'testpage.php?id=' + id + '&hoeveelheid=' +   document.getElementById("hoeveelheid_textfield").value;` has something which is null and is causing problems. Check whether `id` or `document.getElementById("hoeveelheid_textfield")` is null. Probably the latter is null and when you try to access the `value` property the code breaks.